# <enclosure> not working rss and php

Tags: php, rss

I'm working on a rss feed for a website I made. It takes input from my home made news function on the site, which is stored in a MySQL database.

Now I can get the text nicely enough, but when I try to use `<enclosure>` to put in an image, nothing shows up.

The code i use to insert the code is as follows:

```
if($rows['image'] != 0) {
    $image = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dafl_news_imagedb WHERE id = '".$rows['image']."' LIMIT 1"));
    $imageUrl = "http://dafl.dk/content/news/pics/".$image['filename'];
    $imageType = substr($imageUrl, strlen($imageUrl) - 3, 3);
    $enclosedImage = '
    <enclosure url="'.$imageUrl.'" length="0" type="image/'.$imageType.'" />
    ';
    echo $enclosedImage;
}
```

and in the source code of the rss:

```
<enclosure url="http://dafl.dk/content/news/pics/13.png" length="0" type="image/png" />
```

The link to the rss is:
http://dafl.dk/rss/?language=en

(The picture is only included when an image is present for the newspost. Is this a problem - that not all items have an enclosure ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I will keep that in mind, though it shouldn't do anything to my problem, as the source code found with the browser displays the enclosure right ?

Comment: Still a problem? Tested and it loads OK

Comment: OP has left and the problem fixed itself or is no longer an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this link to see if the enclosure tag works in the target browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/rss/tryrss.asp?filename=rss_ex_enclosure

References:
http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_enclosure.asp